# How to show displayName of contact as text?

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages, flutter-android

I want to pick a random number from contact list and show it as Text. Below is what I came up with but when I insert `showNext()` somewhere on `main.dart` as text, I get **Closure: () => Future from Function 'showNext': static.()** instead of a number. How do I show a number?

```
Future<void> showNext() async {
  var status = await Permission.contacts.status;
    if (status.isGranted) {
  var contacts = await ContactsService.getContacts;
  var list = contacts;
    list.shuffle();
  randomNum= (list.first.phones?.first.value ?? '');
  Text('$randomNum');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Future<Widget> showNext() async {
  var status = await Permission.contacts.status;
  if (status.isGranted) {
     final Iterable<Contact> contacts = (await ContactsService.getContacts(withThumbnails: false));
     var list = contacts.toList();
     list=list.shuffle();
     randomNum= (list.first.phones?.first.value ?? '');
     return Text('$randomNum');
  }
```

when you want use:

```
FutureBuilder<String>(
          future: showNext(),
          builder: (context, snapShot) {
            if (!snapShot.hasData) {
              return Container();
            }
            return snapShot.data;
          },
        )
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. for Future<Widget> part, I'm getting 'The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type.'. Official document suggest to use 'throw' or 'return' but not sure how to implement it on. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: you must filter contact list with phone number. with this code:
list .where((element) => element.phones.isNotEmpty)